# Deploying .NET Framework from local file vs URL in a Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: .net, deployment, setup-project

I have a small .NET application that requires the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.  In my setup project, the .NET Framework is a dependency and it is currently using the default value for the InstallURL property (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=131000).  As expected, when the bootstrapper runs on a machine that doesn't already have the framework installed, it will be downloaded from that URL.

This should work fine for most of my users.  However, a few of my users have extremely limited/slow Internet connectivity and downloading the framework installer, even just the client profile, is an undesirable scenario for them.  I know I can bundle the framework installer with my app, change the InstallURL to look for the file locally and then deliver the software on CD but now I have two installers with the only difference being the InstallURL.  So I'm wondering if it's possible to set the InstallURL dynamically at **runtime** based on whether the .NET Framework redistributable installer is detected locally or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're distributing it on a CD, why not just have 1 installer that has the .NET Framework installers all local? Even if the users have a fast internet connection, it's still faster to have it all local.

Otherwise, you could create a custom install action with some way for the user to choose which method for installing the framework, but the application would have to be using a .NET Framework that you know is installed on their machine; a bit of a chicken and egg problem.

Another possibility is to have 2 sperate bootstrappers, one with local install and one with internet install. You'd build the same installer project with different configurations. YOu can use the configuration manager to choose different bootstrappers.